# First Language for the Application

Tags: application, language

I was applying for an academic research program and they wanted to know about my first language.

I am confused about my first language because from childhood on, I used to speak English because English is the medium of teaching in my school, but my parents speak French at home so I used to speak french at home.

Now, which language should I mention as my first language in my application?

Answer (score 1):

Your first language needn't mean chronological. It can mean your primary language for everyday communication. There is no need to overthink it.

If you are fluent in two or more languages you can mention that somewhere.

Comment: So,Will,it be okay if I put English as my First language in the application? Although I always speak French at home?

Comment: Some people are truly bilingual and can say so.  In India, I think it is common among the educated to be trilingual, actually.